# Cannot uninstall SQL Server 2005, no matter what I do

Tags: sql-server

Windows 2003 Server R2 64 bit

I do Control Panel, remove programs, and get:

> Setup failed.. the dialog box disappears so fast that I am unable to write down all the messages, but the items get the red circle with the X inside, indicating something is wrong.

Downloaded `msiinv.exe` and generated the text file. From this I read:

> Microsoft SQL Server Native Client
>   Product code: {79BF7CB8-1E09-489F-9547-DB3EE8EA3F16}

I then run:

```
C:\>msiexec /x {79BF7CB8-1E09-489F-9547-DB3EE8EA3F16}
```

I get:

> The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable
>   Use source:
>   e:\8b67f1db04e16917dc9e5e42\setup\

And yes, `e:\` is the DVD drive on this server. But since SQL 2005 was installed, the server has been colocated, and now runs in a server room 2 hrs drive from where I am located.

And I am not even sure I have the DVD anymore. Why can't I just get the darn thing uninstalled, without it requiring the optical media I used 7 years ago?? I am UN-installing, not installing.

I want to install SQL Server 2008. Will the setup for this offer to remove a previous version? Space is limited - the machine was purchased in 2006, small hard drives. And from what I have read, the advice is to remove 2005 before 2008 is installed.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, it will stubbornly ask for the DVD, no success.
Why 2008? Two reasons: My main customer (large company) run SQL Server 2008, I want an identical development environment. Secondly - any SQL Server above 2008 won't install on my old Win 2003 server.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 isn't necessarily the best solution, particularly on older machines.  If I had a choice between 2008R2 and 2012, I'd use 2008 R2.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909967

Comment: There is no reason to un-install 2005 before installing 2008 unless you want 2008 to be on the default instance. So if you have the space to support both, that's the way to go.

Comment: I agree with Mark Henderson, leave it installed and just disable it in services. SQL Server is designed to have multiple versions on the same server. SQL 2005 doesn't take up much space and you can easily install an instance of a newer SQL Server. I'd probably go for a newer version than 2008 though, although you are installing it on Windows Server 2003 R2 which had end of life in July 2015.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to find an SQL Server 2005 MSI on the Microsoft SQL Server site.  This isn't easy, although you might be able to find it with a keyword search.  You will have to find something other than the minimum install, since you will need at least the client services component.  While this is an installer, it can also be used to remove existing instances.  I suspect that the main reason for this is that third party software (including, for example, BackupExec) have their own instances of SQL Server, and you shouldn't be uninstalling theirs.

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143412%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) might be helpful.

Comment: All services I can think of have already been stopped. That is 4 services starting with the name SQL Server.. I stopped them before my very first attempt to uninstall. If there are further services to stop, I would appreciate their names

Comment: Open up task manager (Ctrl+Shift+Del), make sure 'Show Processes from all users' is checked and you'll get a full list of processes running on the server.  All of the SQL Related processes are named clearly in the 'Description' section.

Comment: How fun.. now I tried to install SQL Server 2008, as an upgrade. I thought that would do the trick. But in the middle of the installation, a dialog box comers up asking for the DVD media I used 7 years ago. I do  not even want to know why it wants that. So the upgrade ended with:
"Your SQL Server 2008 upgrade completed with failures
The Older version of Microsoft SQL Server VSS writer cannot be removed"

Comment: Here are the latest news:

Comment: Here are the latest news:
I used the Windows Install Cleanup utility and removed any trace of SQL Server 2005. Yes, the application is still there on the harddisk, but the Setup for SQL Server 2008 won't see it and stop installing. I must say I am irritated about the "help" on the Microsoft pages, they want me to read books and become an SQL Server expert, trying to teach me a knowledge I do not need. Why not just tell me what steps to carry out to solve certain problems? OK-thanks to those who participated! Windows Install Cleanup is the emergency solution!

Comment: And I was able to install SQL Server 2008 and now it works

Comment: @ingvarius: You should post the solution you found as an answer instead of a mere comment.

Answer (score 0):

may be help ...

Command line, get SQL Server 2005 installed 64-bit component name and Uninstall string:

```
powershell ls HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall -rec ^|gp^|select UninstallString,DisplayName ^|select-string -pattern 'SQL Server 2005' ^|FT Line -Au -Hi
```

Output:

```
@{UninstallString="C:\App64\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\ARPWrapper.exe" /Remove; DisplayName=Microsoft SQL Server 2005 (64-bit)}
@{UninstallString=MsiExec.exe /I{2D8F2A31-E409-43B5-91AF-2FAF678A0052}; DisplayName=Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Analysis Services (64-bit)}
@{UninstallString=MsiExec.exe /I{5867EB9F-3477-489C-8854-8E09BCB24C4C}; DisplayName=Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services (64-bit)}
@{UninstallString=MsiExec.exe /I{62D2F823-0EAA-496D-B0F9-A869BFC51550}; DisplayName=Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Backward compatibility}
@{UninstallString=MsiExec.exe /I{73D8B59D-0BFF-4B5B-A031-FAB3AC629E56}; DisplayName=Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Tools (64-bit)}
@{UninstallString=MsiExec.exe /I{79F1B65E-8FC0-4D03-954D-F9E71C85AEC7}; DisplayName=Microsoft SQL Server 2005 (64-bit)}
@{UninstallString=MsiExec.exe /I{7AC75802-3F1D-4C0C-BAD5-EB0855A28063}; DisplayName=Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Notification Services (64-bit)}
@{UninstallString=MsiExec.exe /I{9ADDBE1C-7180-40E5-967C-C6401ADD9CE6}; DisplayName=Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Integration Services (64-bit)}
```

Command line, get SQL Server 2005 installed 32-bit component name and Uninstall string:

```
powershell ls HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall -rec ^|gp^|select UninstallString,DisplayName ^|select-string -pattern 'SQL Server 2005' ^|FT Line -Au -Hi
```

Output:

```
@{UninstallString="C:\App32\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\ARPWrapper.exe" /Remove; DisplayName=Microsoft SQL Server 2005}
@{UninstallString=MsiExec.exe /I{6FDD4688-E063-401D-B6BE-7234E20B9173}; DisplayName=Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Books Online (English) (September 2007)}
@{UninstallString=MsiExec.exe /I{B0F9497C-52B4-4686-8E73-74D866BBDF59}; DisplayName=Microsoft SQL Server 2005 (SQL2K5LOG)}
```

My old-time SQL Server 2005 Uninstall report:

Uninstall `SQL Server 2005` ... when run `ARPWrapper.exe` in log {454BFA8D-C675-487E-A997-EE8EBF3D2824} error and not uninstall `SQL Server 2005`. Uninstall component:

```
msiexec /I {454BFA8D-C675-487E-A997-EE8EBF3D2824}
```

Silent Uninstall `SQL Server 2005`:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\ARPWrapper.exe" /Remove
```

Uninstall `SQL Server 2005` without install CD:

```
start /wait msiexec /x {79BF7CB8-1E09-489F-9547-DB3EE8EA3F16} SKIPREDISTPREREQS=1 /l*v c:\sqlredist_uninstall.log
```

As variant delete service `sc` command, delete IIS virtual directory, Active Directory registred service SQL, delete registry key and SQL Server folder.

[How to manually uninstall an instance of SQL Server 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909967/en-us)

Thx, @ta.speot.is

registration for the SQL Server 2005 SQL-DMO COM library:

```
regsvr32.exe sqldmo.dll
```

View SQLServer group:

```
dsquery group -name SQLServer* | dsget group -sid -samid
```

Delete SQLServer group:

```
for /f %G in ('dsquery group -name SQLServer* ') do @dsrm %G -c -subtree -uc
```

Delete SQLServer group not prompt for delete confirmation:

```
for /f %G in ('dsquery group -name SQLServer* ') do @dsrm %G -c -subtree -uc -noprompt
```

View SPN:

```
setspn -L %LOGONSERVER:~2%
```

View SPN at login user:

```
setspn -L %USERDNSDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%
```

delete arbitrary SPN:

```
setspn -D <SQL SPN>
```

View SQL Server service:

```
Wmic service where (Caption like "%sql%" OR Name like "%sql%") get Caption, Name
```

Save SQL Server service Report:

```
Wmic service where (Caption like "%sql%" OR Name like "%sql%") get Caption, Name, StartMode, State, PathName, ProcessId,  StartName >> C:\SQLService Report.txt
```

Delete SQL Server Active Directory Helper service:

```
sc delete MSSQLServerADHelper
```

Delete SQL Server Browser service:

```
sc delete SQLBrowser
```

Delete SQL Server Integration Services service:

```
sc delete MsDtsServer
```

Delete SQL Server service:

```
sc delete MSSQL
sc delete MSSQL$Instance
```

Delete SQL Server Agent service:

```
sc delete SqlAgent
sc delete SqlAgent$Instance
```

Delete SQL Server Analysis Services service:

```
sc delete MSOLAP
sc delete MSOLAP$Instance
```

Delete SQL Server Reporting Services service:

```
sc delete ReportServer
sc delete ReportServer$Instance
```

Delete SQL Server FullText Search service:

```
sc delete Msftesql
sc delete Msftesql$Instance
```

View SQL Server Assemblies:

```
dir "%windir%\assembly\GAC\*SQLServer*"
dir "%windir%\assembly\GAC_32\*SQLServer*"
dir "%windir%\assembly\GAC_MSIL\*SQLServer*"
```

Delete SQL Server Assemblies:

```
del /s /q /f  "%windir%\assembly\GAC\*SQLServer*"
del /s /q /f  "%windir%\assembly\GAC_32\*SQLServer*"
del /s /q /f  "%windir%\assembly\GAC_MSIL\*SQLServer*"
```

Delete folder:

```
RD /S /Q "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\90"
RD /S /Q "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server"
RD /S /Q "%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server"
RD /S /Q "%USERPROFILE%\..\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server"
```

Delete SQL Server 2005 registry key:

```
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90" /f
reg delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90" /f
```

Delete startup menu schorcuts:

```
del /s /q "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft SQL Server 2005"
```

View Virtual directory, Default WWW Site:

```
IIsVDir /query w3svc/1/ROOT
```

View Delete `Reports` Virtual directory, Default WWW Site:

```
IIsVDir /delete w3svc/1/ROOT/Reports
```

View Delete `ReportServer` Virtual directory, Default WWW Site:

```
IIsVDir /delete w3svc/1/ROOT/ReportServer
```

Comment: Looks interesting.  Can you provide a reference and/or an explanation?

Comment: It looks similar to one of the commands in the KB article I posted above.